# allowing ping packets from specific ip in windows firewall

Tags: windows, firewall, ping

How do i allow ping packets from a specific ip from my internal network in windows firewall.

Whenever, i tried to set custom inbound rules in windows.

[image]

There does not seem to have a way to achieve this.

Allow access from 192.168.x.x 
Block all access from other ips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As every so often, Microsoft have their very own, and sometimes confusing way of naming things.

Local and remote in a Windows Firewall context don't mean what comes to mind first. The correct translation would be:

```
Local = Destination Address
Remote = Source Address
```

So, in "local" you specify to which destination IP the rule applies. Obviously, this destination address has to be bound to one of your network interfaces. If your machine has only one interface and one IP address, you can just leave it at "any" as it will not reply to other IP addresses than its own anyway.

In "remote" you can now specify the source addresses that are allowed access. These addresses don't have to be remote in the sense that they lie outside of your network.

Hope this clears this up.

Link for further reading: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771905.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the graphic you show, just click on these ip addresses and then add the IP address you want.

Also make sure there are no other rules relating to ping that are less restrictive or this one may not be effective. Please mark as the answer if helpful

Comment: How about the issue with remote IP addresses. I cannot select any ip address as these will mean all IP addresses will allow isnt it?